# store enum val in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have a bunch of JSON objects coming back from a server and I'm trying to normalize them a little in my objective C.

I have this enum:

```
//VP_STATUS
typedef enum {
    VP_STATUS_NA,
    VP_STATUS_STEXP,
    ...
    VP_STATUS_COUNT
} VP_STATUS;
```

I have a function that maps the string in a JSON object (which is an NSMutableDictionary) to this enum and then I try and set a key "status" on the NSMUtableDictionary like so:

```
VP_STATUS status = [myStringToEnumMappingFunction:[p objectForKey:@"status_label"]];
[p setValue:status forKey:@"status"];
```

However, on the setValue:forKey line I get this error:

```
"Implicit conversion of VP_STATUS to id is disallowed with ARC"
```

Do I first have to convert status to something else? If so, then that kind of defeats the purpose of using messages that are defined as VP_STATUS's, doesn't it?

I'm fairly new to objective-c so I could be doing this entirely wrong for all I know and am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enums are like aliases for numbers. The Objective-C collection classes can only store object references.

The error you are getting is saying that a value cannot be converted to an `id` (`id` is another way of writing `NSObject *`), an object pointer.

If you want to store an value in a collection, you need to wrap it in somthing like an `NSNumber`. If you are using LLVM you can do this for example with:

```
[p setValue:@(status) forKey:@"status"];
```

And to compare it again you can turn it back into a number with:

```
VP_STATUS status = [[p valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue];
```